# ffind leaf nodes of the binary search tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

i was asked in a interview question that given the `preorder` traversal of a binary search tree , find out the leaf nodes without constructing the original tree.  i know the property that `binary search tree` has to satisfy but i cannot find any relation into how can it be done utilising this property . only thing i can identify is that the `first node` in th `preorder traversal` will be always be root. also google search did not yield any result for this problem. i do not want the code just a simple hint to begin with would be sufficient.

EDIT: after trying out a lot i got this solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void fl(vector<int> &v, int lo, int hi){
  if (lo>hi) return;
  if (lo == hi) { cout<<"leaf ^^^^^^^ "<< v[hi]<<"\n"; return; }
  int root = v[lo];
  int i;
  for(i = lo+1 ; i <= hi ; i++) if (v[i] > root) break;
  fl(v, lo+1, i -1);
  fl(v, i , hi);
}

int main(){
vector<int> v1 = {8, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7, 10, 14, 13};
vector<int> v2 = {27, 14, 10, 19, 35, 31, 42};
vector<int> v3 = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
fl(v3,0,v3.size()-1);
return 0;
}
```

any suggestions for improvement other than variable names will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

This program should print the leaf nodes from a preOrder of BST. The program is pretty self explanatory.

```
public static void findLeafs(int[] arr) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
            return;

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        for(int n = 1, c = 0; n < arr.length; n++, c++) {
            if (arr[c] > arr[n]) {
                stack.push(arr[c]);
            } else {
                boolean found = false;
                while(!stack.isEmpty()) {

                    if (arr[n] > stack.peek()) {
                        stack.pop();
                        found = true;
                    } else 
                        break;      
                }
                if (found) 
                    System.out.println(arr[c]); 
            }

        }
        System.out.println(arr[arr.length-1]);
    }
```

Comment: a simple explanation to the logic would be very helpful. just what it does

Answer (score 0):

```
def getLeafNodes(data):
    if data:
        root=data[0]
        leafNodes=[]
        process(data[1:],root,leafNodes)
        return leafNodes

def process(data,root,leafNodes):
    if data:
        left=[]
        right=[]
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if data[i]<root: 
                left.append(data[i])
            if data[i]>root:
                right.append(data[i])

        if len(left)==0 and len(right)==0:
            leafNodes.append(root)
            return
        if len(left)>0:
            process(left[1:],left[0],leafNodes)
        if len(right)>0:
            process(right[1:],right[0],leafNodes)
    else:
        leafNodes.append(root)

#--Run--
print getLeafNodes([890,325,290,530,965])
```